# Should I use a loop to fill a Python List with data from a relational DB table?

Tags: python, sql, list

I saw some examples in the internet showing how to connect to a database from Python,
and then to extract data from a table and insert it into a list or print it - using a loop.

Is it obligatory to use the loop? Isn't there a simpler way, like PythonList=SQLRecordSet;
or maybe a way to work directly with a recordset?

I am concerned about the performance and not about the length of the code..

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentation? Do they catalogue a fast way to extract columns from your results? If not, a loop is your only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to approach the performance issue that you are facing :

**1. Fetching all records at one go**

You can use the following statement for most PEP 249 implementations. This essentially returns a list with all rows of the result directly on the client side (Python List).

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

On the other hand , If you are using  MySQLdb or PyMySQL then I suggest using the following.

```
list(cursor)
```

You can use the `rows = cursor.fetchall()` for MySQLdb or PyMySQL too but it is inconsistent with the result as it can return either a List or a Tuple where as `list(cursor)` always returns a list.

**2. Fething one row at a time to reduce memory footprint**

This method stores the result set in the server, thus Python is not required to create a list of tuples. Use this method when the data that is being returned is massive in size.

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(..., cursorclass=cursors.SSCursor)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TABLE')
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```